# Rewrite y múltiples proyectos symfony bajo el mismo directorio

Tags: apache, symfony2

Estoy intentando hacer varios proyectos personales en mi servidor de desarrollo, como una especie de intranet.

Si divido cada proyecto en un `virtualhost` diferente, configuro el archivo `hosts` de cada ordenador y directamente accedo a los distintos proyectos sin ningún problema. El único problema es que en los dispositivos android no puedo modificar el archivo `hosts` y por tanto no puedo acceder a dichas páginas.

Entonces se me ha ocurrido intentar lo siguiente. Por ejemplo:

Tengo tres proyectos symfony en mi carpeta `home`:

```
/home/user/proyectos/proyecto1
/home/user/proyectos/proyecto2
/home/user/proyectos/proyecto3
```

Luego, en el directorio por defecto de apache creo enlaces simbólicos a las carpetas web de cada proyecto:

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/proyectos/proyecto1/web /var/www/html/proyecto1
sudo ln -s /home/user/proyectos/proyecto2/web /var/www/html/proyecto2
sudo ln -s /home/user/proyectos/proyecto3/web /var/www/html/proyecto3
```

Entonces puedo acceder a ellos de la siguiente manera:

```
http://ip-servidor/proyecto1
http://ip-servidor/proyecto2
http://ip-servidor/proyecto3
```

El problema, es que al haber creado los proyectos en un subdirectorio, la regla de `rewrite` de los `.htaccess` de cada proyecto no me funciona y entonces tendría que acceder de esta forma:

```
http://ip-servidor/proyecto1/app.php
```

Creo que la clave está en modificar en los `htaccess` las condiciones de `RewriteCond`, pero no se exactamente que debería añadir o modificar de los mismos.

Estoy usando el `virtualhost` por defecto de apache y los `htaccess` por defecto de los proyectos de symfony.

Configuración del archivo htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Configuración del virtualhost en apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Puedes compartir tu configuración `.htaccess` ??

Comment: Por otro lado, sería factible modificar el servidor DNS de tu dispositivo android y apuntar a un servidor DNS local donde los dominios estén configurados correctamente?

Comment: @Muriano Perdón por la tardanza, he puesto tanto la configuración `.htaccess` como la configuración del `virtualhost`. Lo de crear un servidor DNS local para usar el dispositivo android no se me había ocurrido, ¿es posible hacerlo de manera sencilla?

Comment: Sí, hay aplicaciones que te permiten modificar el servidor DNS del dispositivo. Solo apúntalo a una máquina local que haga de DNS y resuelva el host correctamente hacia las máquinas de prueba.